# YouTube video height ratio, stretch to window width & stretching outside parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, youtube

I have a YouTube embed inside a `div`. This div, `.entry-content`, has a `max-width` of 30em. The YouTube embed I want to be full window width, stretching outside the `#container`. To do this, I have a JS script which I have successfully used to make `img` elements stretch outside `entry-content`. The `img` has `width:100vw` determined in the CSS.

The `iframe` is within a div, `fluid-width-video-wrapper`, as the FitVids jQuery plugnin is used.

Here's the "stretch outside parent element" script:

```
   var bodyWidth = $('body').width();
   var elemWidth = $('.entry-content p').width();
   var margin = bodyWidth-elemWidth;
    var dividedMargin = margin / 2; // Divide the margin by 2
    var negativeMargin = dividedMargin * -1; // set number to negative number
    $('.entry-content iframe').css("margin-left", negativeMargin + "px");
```

I also use this for `$(window).resize()` so that it regardless of margins/paddings stretches full screen.

`width:100vw` width did not work for my iframe in the CSS, so I used a script from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/eFLqJ/).

```
$('.entry-content iframe').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: $(window).innerHeight() + 'px' */});
```

However, as you can see in that fiddle it makes the video **full screen**. I want **full width** with correct aspect ratio. What should I use as `height` in this script?

It has to be fluid, as the window size varies. I use it with `$(window).resize();` too, which slows the page down as hell but that's not a problem for now.

Comment: `iframe{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
}` did you try it in this way?

Comment: It makes the video full screen. I need the aspect ratio to remain intact.

Comment: just to make it clear, show us an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found a container-free solution now, that also works with my snap-to-edge-script.

```
$('.entry-content iframe').css({ width: $(window).innerWidth() + 'px', height: (($(window).innerWidth())*0.5625) + 'px' });
```

As the height of the video should be 56.25%, and the width is 100% of the window inner width, it means the height should be 56.25% of the window width.

Answer (score 1):

No JS needed. Here's all you need to make a responsive player that's 100% of its parent's width and 16:9 aspect ratio.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

.videoContainer {
  width: 100vw; /*now it is 100% of viewport (window) width.*/
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.videoContainer::after {
  padding-top: 56.25%; /* 16:9 ratio - divide height by width and multiply by 100 */
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.videoContainer>iframe{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="videoContainer">
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U5LwcvVAKDg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Good solution, but it's not what I'm after. My video container needs another width than the parent's width. It needs to stretch outside the parent, so that it is a 100% of the window's (or body's) width.

Comment: Just change `%` to `vw`. I edited the code above to show what I mean.

Comment: It works, but I can't understand why it doesn't work with my "snap to left edge" script.

Comment: This really doesn't sound like something you should be using JS for. You should use `fixed` or `absolute` positioning combined with `left:0;` for "snapping" something to the left edge. And I don't understand what your the result you desired was, but it works in Chrome just like I intended it to. Please clarify.

Comment: I have a parent container which has a padding. It is centered with `margin:auto` and after a certain point, the width is fixed. I needed to override the parent container's padding. If the child has `position:absolute`, it's removed from the flow. And if the absolute positioned child is placed in another relative positioned container, that container inherits the parent's padding and max-width. Therefore, I needed a script to calculate the margins for it to snap to the left edge. I tried using `position:absolute` first, but I couldn't find a "clearfix" for it.

Answer (score 0):

is there a possibility if you use "100%" in stead of "px" you get what you're after?

- edit *

i'm sorry i posted the answer and after i posted i red the comment of Ilpo Oksanen but i think this is the solution. and if not please elaborate your question